# How should I store speck?

Tags: storage-method, ham

How should I store speck cured bacon? Fridge, freezer, cupboard? Wrapped, hung etc

Comment: Since I'd never heard of this stuff, I looked it up. You can read more about speck here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find that storing in the fridge is going to give you the longest life span. Hanging will keep keep the process of drying out continuing , which will intensify the flavour but will eventually become jerky texture. Wrapping will keep a little moisture in longer.
If you do keep it for a period of time , you will develop a white mould which I will just cut of as it is just surface . The curing has stopped the pork breaking down .
When I travelled through Spain , all of the city markets would have whole pieces of prosciutto hanging from there stalls that where covered in a fat that was covered in a green mould. When they needed a new piece they cut the mould and fat off and would start slicing for the customers ( some up there for over a year). 
I think the fridge is safer.